# Maui "The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class."

Tags: .net, maui, plugin.media.crossmedia

I am using Xam.Plugin.Media nuget package.

```
await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                Name = fullFileName,
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                MaxWidthHeight = 1000,
                AllowCropping = false
            });
```

Comment: Why are you using a Xamarin plugin?  MAUI has an integrated camera control.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/picker?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android

Comment: I used MediaPicker first. But faced an issue to save a clicked photo to save to android directory even in app's cached directory, and used CrossMedia instead.

Comment: Is there any plugin for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one thing.

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

just update this in MainActivity.cs under Platform>Android folder in MAUI.
Mine has worked perfectly I hope you will find it useful too.